# Disableb communication over COM1 - strange behaviour

Tags: java, serial-port

I have problem, when I start process which doesn't use serial port it disable all communication over COM1, but when I start app from another machine which communicate with this process it works. What could be problem ?
Is seams like when I start Java on that machine it disable communication. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well in order for a Java application to take over some COM port you need to use JavaComm. Are you using JavaComm in your app?

Comment: I have C process which communicate over COM port, my Java app just read from file what that C process write in file. Problem is when I start c process on machine A and Java app on machine B it works, but when I start both on machine A iot doesn't work. JVM is newer on machine A then B. Any help ?

Comment: Try to have the same settings on both machines first. Have you solved this? Java has nothing to do with COM ports if you do not explicitly use JavaComm. So I would setup the machines with identical settings and also have a better look at my C program.